upstream sent unknown "Transfer-Encoding": "" while reading response header from upstream
I have a back-end that sets Cookie header after login for refresh-token.
Now in my front-end (next.js, pages router), server side API calls I set that in the response of that client so the client can make API calls independently and also hydrate it to server-side for SSR.
    try {
        const clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req);
        const { data, headers: returnedHeaders } = await postLogin(undefined, clientIp, 'api/auth/authenticate-anonymous');
        Object.entries(returnedHeaders).forEach(keyArr => {
            res.setHeader(keyArr[0], keyArr[1]);
        })
        res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', '');
        return res.send(data);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send(err);
    }

All this works locally, even I setup nginx on my own PC and it works, but on AWS the APIs give 502 error with logs: upstream sent unknown "Transfer-Encoding": "" while reading response header from upstream
If I don't remove Transfer-encoding then I get this error: upstream sent "Content-Length" and "Transfer-Encoding" headers at the same time while reading response header from upstream.
here is my nginx.conf:
# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    200000;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;

        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  on;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        # include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;

            # Proper proxy headers
            proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

            # Ensure buffering is enabled
            proxy_buffering     on;
            proxy_buffers       16 16k;
            proxy_buffer_size   16k;


            # Remove empty Transfer-Encoding headers from upstream
            proxy_hide_header   Transfer-Encoding;

            # proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            # proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}


Does res.removeHeader('...') work? Also, I would suggest copying only specific, whitelisted headers from api response to your response.

Worked after res.removeHeader('...')
